# Adding Alternative OTP Delivery Option in Azure B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am working on an Azure B2C Custom Policy for user login.

In my user journey, I have a step (OrchestrationStep 4) where the user is asked to enter an OTP (One-Time Password) received via SMS.

However, I would like to provide an alternative option for the user to choose email as the delivery method for the OTP if they are experiencing delays in receiving the SMS.

**I want to know how to modify the following xml so that i could provide this options if user wait for long time for the SMS OTP**

Here is the screen i am talking about:
[image]

```xml
 <ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
  
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify">
      <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.PhoneFactorProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.phonefactor</Item>
        <Item Key="ManualPhoneNumberEntryAllowed">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserIdForMFA" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdForMFA" PartnerClaimType="UserId" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="Verified.OfficePhone" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPhoneNumberEntered" PartnerClaimType="newPhoneNumberEntered" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-MFA" />
    </TechnicalProfile>

  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Comment: You say "if the user wait for long time for the SMS OTP" which I take to mean you want to provide the option for the user to perform MFA via email on that page, instead of as a choice before reaching that page? That's very complicated and can involve a lot of JS and complex custom policies, not just some extra bits on the phone factor technical profile.

Comment: yes, correct. From requirement, we want to provide an alternative way if somehow user mobile is not able to receive sms, we don't want user stop in that page without 2nd option